# Unable to think about a step in proof of a theorem in Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am self studying Analysis from Tom M Apostol and I have a question in proof of Theorem 10.2 .

I am adding it's image ->

[image]

[image]

The question is in the highlighted line

> How is A union of intervals that are disjoint?

I reread the proof but couldn't find it.

Please help.

Comment: So the claim is: if you take $[a,b]$ and subtract a finite number of closed intervals from it, what is left is a finite disjoint union of intervals (open or closed or half-open).

Comment: @GEdgar I got it!!